# creating a function that passes multiple args with operators for filtering dataset using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, function, filter, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

create_filter <- function(dat, ...){
    args <- enquos(...)
    ex_args <- unname(imap(args, function(expr, name) quo(!!sym(name)==!!expr)))
    return(dat %>% filter(!!!ex_args))
}
```

I am creating a function to filter dataset where I pass multiple argument. My current code is working only when I have arguments with equals operator and one argument per column. I also tried my luck with
as.list(match.call()) unsuccesfully. Is there a way to accomplish the following scenarios?

This is working:
create_cohort(dat = iris, Species = 'setosa', Sepal.Length = 5.1)

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa
3          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa.....
```

This is not working:
create_cohort(dat = iris,Species = 'setosa', Sepal.Length >= 5)

expected output:

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa...
```

I also want to try complex filtering where I can use logical operators (OR) and ignore if NA argument is passed. For instance in below case, if setosa is chosen and Sepal.Length is not given(NA) then show 'Sepal.Length' =>5 and for viginica show ignore Sepal.Length criteria and show all rows.

create_cohort(dat = iris, Species = 'setosa'|'virginica', Sepal.Length = NA)

expected:

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3    setosa
          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2    setosa
          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2    setosa
          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2    setosa
          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2    setosa
          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
```

Edit:

Right now this is what I have. It is not working though but what I am doing is for special case when Species = 'setosa' and Sepal.Width = NA, I want to do this --  dat %>% filter(Species == 'setosa' & Sepal.Width > 5 ). For cases, when Species is something else, or Sepal.Width is specified, I want the function to behave normally, as in show the mentioned species and sepal.width. Besides these argument other arguments can be passed so I used '...'

Another problem I am facing is having to assign the argument name to another variable. See how I assigned ln <- Sepal.Width. I can't use Sepal.Width %in% (Sepal.Width) when I filter. Also I want to use (<,>, >=,<=) special operators in my arguments to apply filters. For instance 'Sepal.Width > 3'. Currently that is not working in my code.

```
create_filter <- function(dat, Species, Sepal.Width = NA, ...){
    lst_arg <- list(dat, Species, Sepal.Width, ...)

if (!"data.frame" %in% class(dat)){
    stop("First input must be dataframe")
}
ln <- Sepal.Width
sp <- Species
args <- enquos(...)
ex_args <- unname(imap(args, function(expr, name) quo(!!sym(name)==!!expr)))
dat <- dat %>% filter(!!!ex_args)
if(is.na(Sepal.Width) && (Species == 'setosa')){
    dat %>% filter(Species == 'setosa' & Sepal.Width > 5 )} else{
        dat %>% filter(Sepal.Width %in% (ln),Species %in% (sp))
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a filtered version of iris, or a version that has NA's? I don't understand the logic that would subset the five setosa and three virginica in your last expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler alternative, should work with dplyr 1.0+

```
create_filter <- function(dat, ...){
  dat %>% filter(...)
}
```

Results

```
create_filter(iris, Species == "setosa", Sepal.Length == 5.1)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa
#3          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa
#4          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4  setosa
#5          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa
#6          5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
#7          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4  setosa
#8          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2  setosa

create_filter(iris, Species %in% c("setosa", "versicolor"), Sepal.Width == 3.2)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#1          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#2          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa
#3          5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2     setosa
#4          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#5          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
#6          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#7          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#8          5.9         3.2          4.8         1.8 versicolor
```

---

EDIT:
It sounds like the OP wants to treat NA's differently depending on a variable, e.g. Species. Suppose we have a modified `iris` with NA in Sepal.Width every 3 rows:

```
iris_na <- iris %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Width = if_else(row_number() %% 3 == 0, NA_real_, Sepal.Width))

head(iris_na)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7          NA          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4          NA          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

We could use:

```
create_filter(iris_na, Sepal.Width >= 3.7 | (Species == "setosa" & is.na(Sepal.Width)))
```

to get all examples with wide Sepal.Width (mostly setosas but also one virginica), plus all the setosas with missing Sepal.Width:

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1           4.7          NA          1.3         0.2    setosa
2           5.4          NA          1.7         0.4    setosa
3           4.4          NA          1.4         0.2    setosa
4           5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2    setosa
5           4.8          NA          1.6         0.2    setosa
6           5.8          NA          1.2         0.2    setosa
7           5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4    setosa
8           5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4    setosa
9           5.1          NA          1.4         0.3    setosa
10          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3    setosa
11          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3    setosa
12          5.4          NA          1.7         0.2    setosa
13          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4    setosa
14          5.1          NA          1.7         0.5    setosa
15          5.0          NA          1.6         0.4    setosa
16          4.7          NA          1.6         0.2    setosa
17          5.2          NA          1.5         0.1    setosa
18          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2    setosa
19          5.0          NA          1.2         0.2    setosa
20          4.4          NA          1.3         0.2    setosa
21          4.5          NA          1.3         0.3    setosa
22          5.1          NA          1.9         0.4    setosa
23          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2    setosa
24          4.6          NA          1.4         0.2    setosa
25          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2    setosa
26          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
```

Comment: Thanks. This is good solution indeed but what I want to do is a bit more complex. For instance I want to add special cases like, when Species Setosa is chosen and Sepal.Width is NA or not given, then default it to Sepal.Width >= 5.

Comment: Please explain more. If Sepal.Width is NA, default to Sepal.Width >= 5?

Comment: For the case when Setosa is chosen and Sepal.Width is NA or missing, then the function needs to return rows for Species 'Setosa' with Sepal.Width >=5. It's like a specific rule for certain case.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear to me. If some rows have NA, only return the rows with an available value that is >=5, otherwise return all rows?

Comment: well, it's special case needed to be coded. When I run this function 'create_cohort(dat = iris,Species = 'setosa')' then I would expect to see rows for Setosa with Sepal.Width >=5. Since I have not passed any arguments for Sepal.Width the defualt for Setosa is Sepal.Width >=5. But if I had other Species, then we would not use the same default. It's like If ((Species == 'setosa') && (missing(Sepal.Width)|is.na(Sepal.Width)){Sepal.Width >=5}... if that makes sense

Comment: edited, hopefully I'm understanding your question better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232617/discussion-between-jon-spring-and-utsab-shrestha).